# 1С - Как получить доступ к документам ?

Tags: 1с

Работаю на 1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.19.80), Зарплата и управление персоналом.
В нем есть Документ, который называется **"ТабельУчетаРабочегоВремениОрганизации",**
так вот, скажите как отфильтровать этого документа, по датам Д1,Д2(типа Документ.Выбрать(Д1,Д2)) и вывести на печать ?

Мой вариант не сработал, уже 3-й день разбираюсь в документаций, но ни один из примеров не работает, то ошибкой завершается.

```
Тб = Документы.ТабельУчетаРабочегоВремениОрганизации.ПолучитьСсылку(новый уникальныйИдентификатор);
Таб = Тб.Ссылка;
//Таб.Печать("Табель");
Об = Таб.ПолучитьОбъект();
Об.Печать("Табель");
```

Говорит что, `"Значение не является значением объектного типа"`, как я понял, я не могу получить доступ к документу как объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
Выборка = Документы.ТабельУчетаРабочегоВремениОрганизации.Выбрать(ДатаНач, ДатаКон);
Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл
    Выборка.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект().Печать("Т13");
КонецЦикла;
```